# how to make a view zigzag up the screen?

Tags: android, view, objectanimator

hi i have 2 views that i want to have zig zag up and off the screen. ive tried using object animators like this
float 1

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:ordering="sequentially" >
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="6000"
    android:propertyName="y"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:valueFrom="1500"
    android:valueTo="-1000"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

and float 2

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="3000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="-250"
    android:valueType="floatType"
android:valueTo="50" />
<set
    android:duration="3000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueFrom="-250"
    android:valueTo="50"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
</set>
```

but the results are varied, ie works on tablets but not smaller screens,

I've changed the code to do this programmatically and all it does is slightly change the way I goes up the screen all I want is both balloons to go up the screen at the moment it works beautifully on my tablet but on smaller screens it only shows one balloon. Been struggling on this a while now all views are laid out in XML and are hidden until needed I found there was a way of using fractions in my from and to values but apparently its deprecated any suggestions for a total n00b like me?

Comment: Have you tried to create animation programatically? Have you tried different values for different screens?

Comment: @sandrstar I have tried to implement this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173848/zigzag-animation-of-image-in-android as a possible solution but I'm unable to adjust it to my scenario, this makes the balloons float slightly from left to right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating your own custom interpolator, it basically defines how your animation is going to behave with respect to time, for example accelerate interpolator when used with lets say translate animation, it will accelerate your view, so you might have to create a custom interpolator, that will define your zig zag path, along with translate animation. you can read from here :
[Tutorial on Interpolators](http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1078)